# Can I use an attribute as a link on a button in Email Content?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to use a dynamic URL that is uniquely generated for each lead as a hyperlink on an email out of Marketing Cloud. I changed the link under content and changed it to that attribute, but when I save and test the email it uses the old Static link that we used to have that is no longer saved under the email content.

I have the link set to Other and the Attribute, which is populating under subscribers correctly, as the URL.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261466/ampscript-redirectto-links-breaking-directing-to-https-click-email

Comment: By Test, do you mean preview or do you mean send a test email. As it is showing the old link and not the new one, it makes me think there is some sort of caching issue. Other thought is that potentially something is causing your change to not save. When you reopen this, does it show what you put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out myself, but then I ran into another problem. You have to change the Email Content, save the content, and then update the email content in the journey as well. I thought that if I updated the content that the journey used it would automatically grab the new content, but it does not unless specifically instructed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).